# how to get changing input value from v-for in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

This is a short example that illustrates what I'm curious to solve.

This example will basically display items from an item list and allow a user to adjust the quantity of items through an input box. The default is set to 0 but the customer/user can change it up to 10.

I need to be able to access 2 things: the name of the item ("itemv") and the quantity (through the "val" variable?) of every single adjusted input box in that v-for loop.

Accessing the name of the item is easy, since I already have the items passed as a prop. I can just iterate through. But I am not sure how to access the input values that the user changes.

Do I have to use the key attribute here? How do I iterate through all those InputBox components and get the value?

```
<template>

  <div>
      <span v-for="(itemv,  index) in items" :key="index">
          <p>{{itemv}}
            <InputBox :value="val" :min="0" :max="10"></InputBox>
          </p>
    </span>

  </div>

</template>


<script>
import { EventBus } from '../event-bus.js';
import InputBox from "./InputBox";

export default {
  name: 'ProductsPage',
  components: {InputBox},
  props: ['items'],
  data: function () {
  return {
      val: 0,
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with that number

Comment: I want to be able to associate it with each proper itemv and pass it through a post request to backend. Probably aggregate them both in an array or something and pass that with axios.

Comment: What is the structure of `items` here? It is an array of objects or just a simple array? If array of objects what properties does it have?

Answer (score 1):

You can `v-model` to `itemv` if it's an object in order to capture the input values like:

```
<span v-for="(itemv,  index) in items" :key="index">
          <p>{{itemv}}
            <InputBox v-model="itemv.val" :min="0" :max="10"></InputBox>
          </p>
</span>
```

Then You can iterate trough them in your methods like:

```
let total = 0;
for(let i in this.items) total += items[i].val || 0;
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below, associate the v-model of input as an attribute of the itemv

```
<span v-for="(itemv,  index) in items" :key="index">
      <p>{{itemv}}
        <InputBox v-model="itemv.value" :min="0" :max="10"></InputBox>
      </p>
</span>
```

This will enable you to get a particular value for your particular item in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `v-model` to get the changed input value

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="box in itemsArr" :key="box.label">
      <input-box v-model="box.value" :min="0" :max="10" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemsArr: [
        { value: 0, label: "a" },
        { value: 0, label: "b" },
        { value: 0, label: "c" }
      ]
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

if you change some chars in `input-box` component, the value of item in `itemsArr` will change to the same string or number.